# Unable to use "Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync" method

Tags: office-js

I am working on Word Addin using Office JS , in this Addin I am using Dialog API 
to display a dialog , In this dialog  when I try to use "Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync" method it displays

> Unable to get property 'customXmlParts' of undefined or null reference error.

Any idea what is the issue ?

Comment: I met the same problem and didn't fix it, any solution found later please ?

Comment: It's been long time, don't remember how I fixed the issue.

Comment: @user1108069 See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have included the Office.js reference in the dialog page (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js).

Answer (score 0):

There are only two APIs allowed inside the Dialog: `messageParent` and `isSetSupported`. If you want to work with `Office.context.document.customXmlParts`, you need to have that functionality in the parent page, usually a task pane. You can trigger the action in the dialog by having the dialog pass a signal to the parent page with `messageParent`. A handler in the parent page for the message received event can be defined to call the `Office.context.document.customXmlParts`-related APIs. It would appear to the user that they are carrying out the action with the dialog.

Comment: Hi Rick I met the problem in a taskpane, so I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435220/office-context-document-customxmlparts-is-undefined , any idea please?