# Office.context.document.customXmlParts is undefined

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm working on an Excel addin using Office JS, in a taskpane, I call Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync, but it throws exception 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByNamespaceAsync' of undefined', namely Office.context.document.customXmlParts is undefined

The office-js version is 1.0.52

The below way to get the customXmlParts works:

```js
    return await Excel.run(async ctx => {
        const workbook = ctx.workbook;
        workbook.load("customXmlParts");
        await ctx.sync();
        const items = workbook.customXmlParts.items;
        ...
    }
```

But I need to call getByNamespaceAsync to use the Office.CustomXmlPart.value.addHandlerAsync in the callback, so the above way doesn't suit.

Any idea please?

Comment: Please provide the code that's causing the error. Also, can you reproduce the error in the [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) tool?

Comment: I tested the code `if (Office.context.document.customXmlParts) { console.log("is not undefined"); } else { console.log("is undefined"); }` in Script Lab, and got the same result, "is undefiend"

Comment: I can reproduce. So I think this is probably a new bug. Please raise this issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: @RickKirkham hi, as the link posted by MandytMSFT, the Office.context.document.customXmlParts doesn't work in Excel, so not sure if it's a bug, maybe it's a feature that is not implemented so far but will be in the future, still need to raise the issue please?

Comment: No need to raise the issue. @MandyMSFT nailed it. It's just not supported in Excel. I don't think it ever will be supported in Excel, because `Excel.Workbook.customXmlParts` is meant to be used for XML part management in Excel. I think you're going to have to find a way to carry our your scenario without `Office.CustomXmlPart.value.addHandlerAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Office.context.document.customXmlParts only supported on word. Pls use Excel.Workbook.customXmlParts instead for Excel Addin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets#customxmlparts

Comment: Really appreciate your link above because it tells me Office.context.document.customXmlParts doesn't work in Excel, but Excel.Workbook.customXmlParts is not what I wanted, because I can't use it to use Office.CustomXmlPart.value.addHandlerAsync. Anyway, thank you for your answer